# C# XML deserialization to DataSet within one table

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I'm making a custom XML parser to read/edit a set of XML documents (21).
All of them are having their own XSD and are valid XML docs. The XSD files were converted to serializable *.cs classes with xsd.exe tool.

For clarification, I can read the XML succefully, but I can't read the child node attributes/value properly so it is displayed in the DataGridView (the attribute wPath in the resourceUrl node, see example below)

Since I don't have enough experiences w/XML and serialization, I'm uncertain about the following:
Is .NET providing some built-in functionality to handle reading child node attributes/values or I should have to read it manualy?

In the following example, all the attributes and its values are succefully loaded in the DataSet/DataTable - except the resourceUrl node - the column is there, but the value is just the name of the type.

Example XML:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="utf-8" ?>
<c:product_resourceUrls xmlns:sql="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-sql" xmlns:c="http://example.com/data/scl/product_resourceUrl">
  <y0:product_resourceUrl xmlns:y0="http://example.com/data/scl/product_resourceUrl" ExternalProductId="90AI8-3I" ProductSKU="90AI8-3I" Name="/images/path_to_product_img.jpg">
    <y0:resourceUrl WPath="/images/path_to_product_img.jpg"/>
  </y0:product_resourceUrl>
</c:product_resourceUrls>
```

The expected output in the DataTable is row like this (I don't mind the column order):

```
     WPath       | ExternalProductId | ProductSKU |      Name
"/images/p..."   |    "90AI8-3I"     |   90AI8-3I | "/images/p..."
```

Thank you in advance for any relevant hint ^^

Comment: could you share your parsing code you have created so far?

Comment: @Tim Rutter sure, it's relatively simple:
```C#
XmlSerializer xml = new XmlSerializer(obj.GetType()); // The obj variable is one of the 21 XSD schemes
FileStream stream = new FileStream(ofd.FileName, FileMode.Open);
/*
* Here is a bit of code where I'm specifying which scheme should be used and then the xml.Deserialize() is used.
*/
```

Comment: you need to be more explicit about what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class Product
{
    public string ExternalProductId { get; set; }
    public string ProductSKU { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string WPath { get;  set; }
}
```

Usage

```
var doc = XDocument.Load(xml);
var urls = doc.Root.Nodes().Cast<XElement>();

List<Product> products = new List<Product>();

foreach (XElement url in urls)
{
    products.Add(new Product()
    {
        ExternalProductId = url.Attribute("ExternalProductId").Value,
        ProductSKU = url.Attribute("ProductSKU").Value,
        Name = url.Attribute("Name").Value,
        WPath = ((XElement)url.FirstNode).Attribute("WPath").Value,
    });
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. So I should give up the xsd.exe generated classes and do it this way? I'm curious because there are 20 more XSD's which are waaay more complex than the example above.

Comment: @netrag hm maybe you should provide or attach a link to a sample XML document and it's XSD

Comment: Examples are on the pastebin: XML file: https://pastebin.com/sv6Qxm4x
XSD File: https://pastebin.com/NihPvQJ6

Comment: I suppose you've already tried doing something like `DataSet ds = new DataSet();
ds.ReadXmlSchema(xsd); ds.ReadXml(xml); BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource(); bSource.DataSource = ds.Tables[1]; dataGridView1.DataSource = bSource;` and the problem is there's missing data?

Comment: @netrag the thing is every `xsd:complexType` will generate a separate table in the dataset, so it's up to you to either edit the xsd or parse the datatables using code.. I don't know what else to say.

Comment: Exactly just as you wrote it, that was the 2.nd solution (after the 1.st try with the generated classes. The only difference between these two solutions is: By using generated class, the child element is "partially" there - the column is there, but the value is the name of the type (from the generated class). The column is missing completely by using the second solution.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't know about the ```complexType``` :X Now it makes sense to me and now I think I know, what to do next. Thank you very much!

Comment: @netrag I think you should consider also the `Datatable.Merge()` method. Using the pastebin you provided as example, since tables 2 and 3 are related between eachother, you could do `var merged_table = ds.Tables[1];  merged_table.Merge(ds.Tables[2]);` this way you will have all the data into a single table. This is possible because both tables share the same schema. I don't know however if you will be able to get away with this for every single one of your documents.

Comment: @netrag what I mentioned above would return the following output: [link](https://ibb.co/3hGZfGm)

Comment: I did that (merging) and it went good. But then, the other Xsd didn't like it (I'm trying to do it "generic" as possible).
And then, there is one scheme and Xml, that throws "Column 'nVariantId' does not allow DBNull.Value" when I try to merge the tabs. 'nVariantId' is an attribute, that is used in more Xml Elements within one Xml file, and as an Xml amateur, I'm clueless...

Comment: @netrag sorry, but I dont think I can help you further then